# radeon.dpm=1 invalid on 13.04 w/4850

Tags: 13.04, radeon, fan, fancontrol

I'm trying 13.04 using the open source Radeon drives (I think that's the same as Gallium but correct me if I'm confused).  This is on an 4850 card, so would need legacy proprietary drivers, which aren't 13.04 compatible (I did the xserver downgrade to use them on 12.04 but don't want to go that route on 13.04).

The drivers are working except I can't get the fan/power settings to change.  I tried adding radeon.dpm=1 to grub, but I get this error in syslog at boot (and the system comes up with poor (2d?) graphics):

```
Aug 14 20:26:23 xxxx-xxxx kernel: [    5.115756] radeon: `1' invalid for parameter `dpm'
```

Here's some info from a few commands that might help identify if I'm doing something wrong.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV770 [Radeon HD 4850]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe8e0000-fe8effff ioport:b000(size=256) memory:fe8c0000-fe8dffff




 modinfo radeon
filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    ATI Radeon
author:         Gareth Hughes, Keith Whitwell, others.
<bunch of firmware listing>
radeon/RV710_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV730_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV730_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV770_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV770_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RS780_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RS780_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV670_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV670_pfp.bin
<bunch of firmware listing>
srcversion:     9F592710CB27B4A29EE5630
<bunch of alias pci: listings>
depends:        drm,drm_kms_helper,ttm,i2c-algo-bit
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.8.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           no_wb:Disable AGP writeback for scratch registers (int)
parm:           modeset:Disable/Enable modesetting (int)
parm:           dynclks:Disable/Enable dynamic clocks (int)
parm:           r4xx_atom:Enable ATOMBIOS modesetting for R4xx (int)
parm:           vramlimit:Restrict VRAM for testing (int)
parm:           agpmode:AGP Mode (-1 == PCI) (int)
parm:           gartsize:Size of PCIE/IGP gart to setup in megabytes (32, 64, etc) (int)
parm:           benchmark:Run benchmark (int)
parm:           test:Run tests (int)
parm:           connector_table:Force connector table (int)
parm:           tv:TV enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           audio:Audio enable (1 = enable) (int)
parm:           disp_priority:Display Priority (0 = auto, 1 = normal, 2 = high) (int)
parm:           hw_i2c:hw i2c engine enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           pcie_gen2:PCIE Gen2 mode (-1 = auto, 0 = disable, 1 = enable) (int)
parm:           msi:MSI support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           lockup_timeout:GPU lockup timeout in ms (defaul 10000 = 10 seconds, 0 = disable) (int)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this, but for the sake of anyone who lands here searching while fighting with a HD4850...  Do yourself a favor - for $40 I got a fanless Nvidia GT610.  Installed and working perfectly in 10 minutes.  Proprietary drivers installed simply through ubuntu's 'Additional Drivers' UI.  Silent.  30W less power.  Just as fast desktop (probably slower games).  XBMC even uses GPU decoding!  I wish I could have the hours of my life I wasted on ATI back.

Answer (score 1):

why it didn't work is simple: you used a kernel (3.8) that didn't have yet support for dpm - go with kernel 3.11 / Ubuntu 13.10

if you use a linux distribution with 3.11 it most likely includes an updated version of Mesa (9.2) that offers UVD (hardware video acceleration) for radeon cards too.

to check if everything went fine after setting radeon.dpm=1 in grub:

```
modinfo radeon
vermagic:       3.11.0-4-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           dpm:DPM support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)


dmesg | grep dpm
[drm] radeon: dpm initialized
```

more info:
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQyNDE

Comment: Your answer was spot on - works on 13.10 as you suggested.  I didn't get as far as trying the UVD accelleration though, since even on "power level 0" "low" power, the card is still way too loud for a HTPC.It's unfortunate... as I was able to set a RPM vs. TEMP curve in windows and keep it about 40% fanspeed at idle (or playing movies) which made a huge difference in sound.  That was compared to the default of 60% (it must be running 60% or faster currently... but not blaring 100% or something).

I appreciate the answer though.